# create and use NumPy array with dtype of builtin int

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

I'm using a method from somewhere else which needs the built-in type of integers `int` and not the type NumPy creates. Here is a simplification:

```
a = np.arange(6, dtype='int').reshape(2,3)
b = a.tolist()

f(a[0,0]) # fails
f(b[0][0]) # works
```

fail gives error message:

> TypeError: bpy_struct: item.attr = val: expected sequence items of
>   type int, not numpy.int64

Although `tolist()` works, I loose NumPy in the process. My question is, can I maintain the NumPy form and flexibility, with the built-in type of int?

Comment: Cast it to Python's integer object by using `int()`.

Comment: I want to maintain the array as a NumPy array, with a dtype of the built-in int type. `int(a)` fails.

Comment: I meant `f(int(a[0,0]))`.

Comment: Please double check the part where I said "My question is..."

Comment: No, I don't think that is possible at the array level because Python's int is not a primitive data type and has no size limitation at all.

Comment: aha! OK thanks! That helps me understand what's going on. NumPy needs to allocate memory, so it has to choose the number of bytes up front. Thankyou @AshwiniChaudhary

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It may help to distinguish between what the array stores in its data buffer, and what it returns via indexing.

```
a=np.arange(6,dtype=int).reshape(2,3)
```

Its attributes, `a.__array_interface__`

```
{'strides': None,
 'descr': [('', '<i4')],
 'shape': (2, 3),
 'data': (171366744, False),
 'version': 3,
 'typestr': '<i4'}
```

The values are stored a 24 bytes (6 * 4), starting at the `data` memory location.

`a[0,0]` isn't just 4 bytes from the data buffer.  It is really a single item 0d array.  Technically its type is `np.int32`, but it has many of the same attributes and methods as an `np.ndarray`:

```
In [431]: a[0,0].__array_interface__
Out[431]: 
{'strides': None,
 'descr': [('', '<i4')],
 'shape': (),
 '__ref': array(0),
 'data': (171093512, False),
 'version': 3,
 'typestr': '<i4'}
```

`.item()` method can be used to pull that value out of the array object.  In many cases an `int32` can be used just like a Python primitive `int`, but evidently your function is picky, performing some sort of `isinstance(i,int)` test.

```
type(a[0,0])  # numpy.int32
type(a[0,0].item()) # int
type(int(a[0,0])  # int
```

`a.tolist()[0][0]` because that array method is designed to construct a nested list of Python primitives, stripped of all `ndarray` attributes.  In effect it does `.item()` at the lowest level.  Effectively it is:

```
In [444]: [[j.item() for j in i] for i in a]
Out[444]: [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5]]
```

Comment: _Because_ `a[0, 0]` is 'array-like', one could of course apply `tolist` **after** the indexing: `a[0, 0].tolist()` _will_ return an `int`. (Funnily enough, this means that `tolist` doesn't always return a `list`. Figure that.) Of course, `a[0, 0].item()` and `int(a[0, 0])` are both much better at revealing the intention of what's going on.

Comment: OK this is new to me @das-g. And that's interesting (`tolist` applied to single NumPy element)!

Comment: While technically the answer to my question is "No, you can't" (comment by @AshwiniChaudhary) this answer gives a lot of helpful information to understand what is going on. Thanks!

Comment: Well, both built-in and Numpy float types actually give an array of scalars. I'd ask explicitly again the OP question: is there really no way to create an array of integers(not array-like)?