# Python - mean of a numpy array, decimal places, float and Decimal

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, decimal

Consider the following code (Python 3.8.0 on MINGW64 in MSYS2 on Windows 10):

```py
import numpy as np
from decimal import Decimal

aa = [25744, 25687, 25641, 25601, 25566, 25533, 25505, 25479, 25456, 25435]
npaa = np.array(aa)

print(np.mean(npaa))                            # 25564.7
print(0.001*np.mean(npaa))                      # 25.564700000000002

print( Decimal(np.mean(npaa)) )                 # 25564.70000000000072759576141834259033203125
print( Decimal(0.001)*Decimal(np.mean(npaa)) )  # 25.56470000000000125976798437
```

So, the mean of the above list of integers is at first printed as 25564.7, which is what I expect and want to get.

But then, as soon as I multiply this number with 0.0001, I get a ton of decimals, likely because of float (im)precision.

So, I thought - what the heck, I'm just going to use Decimal class, I should then get the "right" amount of decimals in this case.

But then, as soon as I try `Decimal(np.mean(npaa))`, I get the mean itself as a bunch of decimals: 25564.70000000000072759576141834259033203125

So apparently, `np.mean(npaa)` already contained those decimals - but for some reason, they just weren't printed.

So this is the thing - since all I have in the list are integers, and there are 10 of them in the list, mathematically (in this case) it is impossible I get any other result but a number with 1 decimal, and 1 decimal only.

Now, I could get around this with printing the mean number as a string, and formatting as 1 decimal, as in `"{:.1f}".format(np.mean(npaa))`, then use that string as source of decimal - and that works; but then, I have other arrays which are not 10 in length, and I would like the minimum amount of decimals to be present in the variable automatically - without me manually having to figure out what number of decimals I should expect, and then formatting them as string.

So I can just try using an array of Decimals, (as the linked post tried to do), which is not exactly trivial:

```py
print( np.array(aa, dtype=Decimal) )          # [25744 25687 25641 25601 25566 25533 25505 25479 25456 25435]
print( np.array(aa).astype(Decimal) )         # [25744 25687 25641 25601 25566 25533 25505 25479 25456 25435]
print( np.array([Decimal(ax) for ax in aa]) ) # [Decimal('25744') Decimal('25687') Decimal('25641') Decimal('25601') Decimal('25566') Decimal('25533') Decimal('25505') Decimal('25479')  Decimal('25456') Decimal('25435')]

print( np.mean( np.array([Decimal(ax) for ax in aa]) ) )                # 25564.7
print( type(np.mean( np.array([Decimal(ax) for ax in aa]) )) )          # <class 'decimal.Decimal'>
print( Decimal(0.001)*np.mean( np.array([Decimal(ax) for ax in aa]) ) ) # 25.56470000000000053217222296
```

... and yet, *even* if I have now a `Decimal` of 25564.7, and a `Decimal` 0.001 when I multiply them - in `Decimal` domain! - I *still* get 25.56470000000000053217222296 !?

How the hell can I get Python to calculate 0.001*25564.7 as 25.5647, which is what it should be - without having to "cast", that is, print the decimal/floating value as a string with a limited number of decimals? Wasn't the Decimal class supposed to be able to do that?

---

EDIT: So, I tried also `sum()/len()` approach, as in the linked post - I thought at first it does it, but no:

```
print( sum(aa)/len(aa) )                # 25564.7
print( 0.001*sum(aa)/len(aa) )          # 25.5647
print( Decimal(0.001*sum(aa)/len(aa)) ) # 25.564699999999998425437297555617988109588623046875

print( sum(npaa)/len(npaa) )                 # 25564.7
print( 0.001*sum(npaa)/len(npaa) )           # 25.5647
print( Decimal(0.001*sum(npaa)/len(npaa)) )  # 25.564699999999998425437297555617988109588623046875
```

https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

> Incidentally, the decimal module also provides a nice way to “see” the exact value that’s stored in any particular Python float

https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html

> Decimal numbers can be represented exactly. In contrast, numbers like `1.1` and `2.2` do not have exact representations in binary floating-point. End users typically would not expect `1.1 + 2.2` to display as `3.3000000000000003` as it does with binary floating-point.

So, if `Decimal` numbers can be represented exactly, why do I get the same floating-point imprecision when I use the `Decimal` class in this context?

Comment: Please refer to this page: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

Comment: Thanks, @Fourier - that page already discusses floating point imprecision, which is what I tried to handle with Decimal class, and https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html says that "Decimal numbers can be represented exactly" - so, the link you posted doesn't explain to me why does `Decimal` fail to do that in this particular case.

Comment: `Decimal(0.001)` is creating a Decimal from a `float`. `float` rounding has already occurred. If you want something that represents exactly one thousandth, use `Decimal('0.001')`.

Comment: Remember that Decimal isn't exact either, though. It's just decimal.

Comment: Calling `Decimal` on the result of a computation doesn't cause that computation to be performed in decimal. It just builds a `Decimal` out of whatever came out of the computation. The computation is unaffected.

Comment: Many thanks, @user2357112 - I think "*Decimal(0.001) is creating a Decimal from a float, float rounding has already occurred. If you want something that represents exactly one thousandth, use Decimal('0.001').*" (that is, a string) is the important part that I missed. Feel free to post this as an answer, I'll accept it

Answer (score 1):

OK, I'm going to post this as an answer - thanks to the comments by @user2357112, now I'm aware that regardless of how a float may be printed at first (possibly rounded), if I throw/cast that float into a `Decimal`, I'll still get the same rounding error. So, I either have to work on level of integers from start, or on levels of strings.

So, in this particular case (ints in array, looking for a mean), I can do this:

```py
tmean = Decimal(int(sum(npaa)))/Decimal(len(npaa))
print( type(tmean), tmean ) # <class 'decimal.Decimal'> 25564.7
```

So, I basically first run the sum of the array, which results with an integer, which I cast to `Decimal`. Note that, I first have to cast the sum into a Python builtin `int`, otherwise:

```py
Decimal(sum(npaa))/Decimal(len(npaa)) # TypeError: conversion from numpy.int32 to Decimal is not supported
```

And it turns out, it is quite difficult to "cast" the entire numpy array to a Python builtin `int`: [create and use NumPy array with dtype of builtin int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31905610/create-and-use-numpy-array-with-dtype-of-builtin-int) - so the only thing left, is to cast the sum, as a single number, to built-in `int`.

But once that is done, I have the mean calculation as division of two `Decimal` class integers - in which case, I can reasonably expect the correct number of decimals (in this case, one) in the final calculation of the mean number.

EDIT: and in the end, if I want to calculate this mean times 0.001, I need to use it as a string in `Decimal('0.001')*tmean` to get the right number of decimals - if I just use `Decimal(0.001)` with a float argument, the float imprecision would have already crept in, and just using the `Decimal` class cannot help anymore.